# Check If JavaScript Procedure is Already Running

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

i have requirement where i would like to check if the Procedure that i am going to run is already  in running status ;
I am planning to check using following Query

```
 "SELECT EXECUTION_STATUS FROM SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.QUERY_HISTORY WHERE EXECUTION_STATUS ='RUNNING'" ;
```

OR Should I use  "

```
SELECT EXECUTION_STATUS FROM DATABASE.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.QUERY_HISTORY WHERE EXECUTION_STATUS ='RUNNING'"
```

if Column value is RUNNING then its instance is already running.
Let me know if this approach is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `EXECUTION_STATUS` column of `QUERY_HISTORY` to determine whether a stored procedure call is still running or not.

However, in this case, the `ACCOUNT_USAGE.QUERY_HISTORY` view cannot be used because this view has some delay. In other words, it cannot capture the real-time execution status. So, the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.QUERY_HISTORY` table function is preferred.

Below is an example of how to use the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.QUERY_HISTORY` table function in this use case. Please note that `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.QUERY_HISTORY` is a table function, not a view, so you have to use the `TABLE()` wrapper to use it as below:

**Worksheet 1:**

```sql
-- Sample stored procedure just waiting for 60 seconds

create or replace procedure sp1 ()
returns varchar
language javascript
as 'snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: "select system$wait(60);"}).execute();'
;

call sp1();
```

**Worksheet 2:**

```sql
select start_time, query_id, query_text, execution_status
from table(information_schema.query_history())
where execution_status = 'RUNNING'
;
/*
START_TIME  QUERY_ID    QUERY_TEXT  EXECUTION_STATUS
2021-10-26 08:25:56.969 +0200   019fdc41-0000-2c1d-0000-3f8100091e56    select start_time, query_id, query_text, execution_status  from table(information_schema.query_history())  where execution_status = 'RUNNING'  ;    RUNNING
2021-10-26 08:25:53.869 +0200   019fdc41-0000-2c5c-0000-3f81000935aa    select system$wait(60); RUNNING
2021-10-26 08:25:53.515 +0200   019fdc41-0000-2c5c-0000-3f81000935a6    call sp1(); RUNNING
*/
```

Please note that the above result from the `QUERY_HISTORY` table function with `EXECUTION_STATUS = 'RUNNING'` includes the `QUERY_HISTORY` query itself. So, if you only collect the `EXECUTION_STATUS` column as your example, it's difficult to distinguish whether the running query is the stored procedure call or not.

Therefore, if a human uses the status check query to check visually, the query should include other columns like `QUERY_ID`, `START_TIME` and `QUERY_TEXT` to distinguish the stored procedure call.

Otherwise, if any automation uses the status check query, the query should have another filter (`WHERE` clause) to distinguish the stored procedure call as below:

```sql
select query_id
from table(information_schema.query_history())
where execution_status = 'RUNNING'
and query_text ilike 'call%'
;
/*
QUERY_ID
019fdc48-0000-2c1d-0000-3f8100091e6e
*/
```

You can change the pattern in the new filter to distinguish different stored procedure calls, and also you can use a query tag:

**Worksheet 1:**

```sql
alter session set query_tag = 'ws1';
call sp1();
```

**Worksheet 2:**

```sql
alter session set query_tag = 'ws2';
call sp1();
```

**Worksheet 3:**

```sql
select query_tag, query_id
from table(information_schema.query_history())
where execution_status = 'RUNNING'
and query_text ilike 'call%'
;
/*
QUERY_TAG   QUERY_ID
ws2 019fdc4b-0000-2c5c-0000-3f8100093642
ws1 019fdc4b-0000-2c1d-0000-3f8100091ec6
*/

select query_tag, query_id
from table(information_schema.query_history())
where execution_status = 'RUNNING'
and query_text ilike 'call%'
and query_tag = 'ws2'
;
/*
QUERY_TAG   QUERY_ID
ws2 019fdc4b-0000-2c5c-0000-3f8100093642
*/
```